# Java - Write a program that prompts the user to input an integer and then outputs both the individual digits of the number and the sum of the digits

Tags: java

I have seen this question asked a few times, but all of the responses have included functionality that I haven't learned yet in this class and am I sure there must be a way to do it with only what I have learned.  No arrays, etc... just loops and prior.  I am not really looking for the answer, but just some direction.  I have included the code I have already done.  The program needs to be able to hand negative numbers, the sum and then print in the proper order.  Right now my code does everything except print in the proper order.  I understand why it is printing in reverse order (because the loop gets rid of and then prints the last number in the int), but I can't seem to figure out a way to change it.  I have tried converting it to a string, char and just can't get it.  Please take a look, and provide some guidance if you don't mind.  thank you in advance.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        int sum;
        int temp;

        System.out.print("Enter an integer, positive or negative: ");
        num = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        if (num < 0)
            num = -num;

        sum = 0;

        while (num > 0) {
            temp = num;
            sum = sum + num % 10;           //Extracts the last digit and adds it to the sum
            num = num / 10;                 //removes the last digit
            System.out.print(temp % 10 + " ");
        }

        System.out.println(" and the sum is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: A suggestion to make your code more readable: rather than do the same modulo operation twice create a variable to store the value of the first modulo operations, say "int digit" and use that for both your summation and printing.  Place your declarations for sum and digit into your loop.

Comment: Nate,  thank you and I understand what you are saying about creating a variable to make the code more readable, however I am not positive which particular one you are referring to here.  Are you talking about the 10 or the 0 or?

Comment: I would use int digit = sum + num % 10;  then add digit to sum then do whatever else you need to do such as suggested by jimW.

Comment: Thanks Nate, I understand that now.  rather than having the equation in the loop set the equation to a value and use that value.  That makes sense, if I was writing a larger program it would make the code easier to read/modify.  Even though this is a small program it is probably good practice to do that.  thanks again Nate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing what they've taught you in class so far, an easy albeit inefficient thing to do is to recreate the number as string.

```
String numbers = "";
while (num > 0) {
    temp = num;
    sum = sum + num % 10;           //Extracts the last digit and adds it to the sum
    num = num / 10;                 //removes the last digit
    // System.out.print(temp % 10 + " ");
    numbers = (temp % 10) + " " + numbers;
}

System.out.println(numbers + "and the sum is " + sum);
```

You were already grabbing the ones digit with (temp % 10) and then right shifting the original number with num = num / 10. There are other data structures you could use like a Stack or a LinkedList that are more natural to use in a situation like yours, or you could use a StringBuilder to append the digits to the end and then use the reverse() method to get them back in the correct order, but those data structures probably come after Arrays which you mentioned you didn't know.

Given those constraints, I used String concatenation. In general here is what happens:

```
String numbers = "";
num = 123;
digit = num % 10; // digit=3
num /= 10; // num=12
numbers = digit + " " + numbers; // numbers="3 " uses old value on right side of the equals

// next iteration
digit = num % 10; // digit=2
num /= 10; // num=1
numbers = digit + " " + numbers; // numbers="2 3 " see how the digit is put to the left of the old value

// last iteration
digit = num % 10; // digit=1
num /= 10; // num=0
numbers = digit + " " +numbers; // numbers="1 2 3 " notice there is an extra space at the end which is ok for your example
```

Comment: Thank you Jim, I will be trying this later today.  thank you for responding.

Comment: Jim, thank you I was able to get the program working using this.  It was so simple, I'm almost ashamed of myself for not figuring that out!  Thanks again.  Now, I would like to make sure that I understand what the code is actually doing here.  it's creating a String (numbers) and setting it to the remainder of each loop.  if 123 is entered it will be 3, 2, 1 as it goes through the loop.  How does it know to print 1 2 3?

Comment: I'll add some comments to the answer so I'll have more room

Comment: Jim, I appreciate you taking the time to not only provide me help in solving this problem, but also explaining it to me.  Your explanation was very helpful and I know understand.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Set a counter, loop num/10, if result>0 counter++. In the end, counter+1 will be the number of digits

Comment: Thank you Leon, I will be trying this later today.  thank you for responding.

Comment: Leon, I was able to get the code to work with Jim's advice above, however if there is another way to accomplish it as you suggest, I would like to learn it as well, but I'm having trouble visualizing how it would work.

Comment: Suppose that you input an integer like 4362, you can get the number of digits, which is 4. 4362/1000=4, 4362-4000=362, 362/100=3, 362-300=62....

Answer (score 0):

```
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers:  ");

        int number_entered = input.nextInt();
     
        int sum = 0;
        String reserve = "";
        if (number_entered < 0 ) {
            number_entered = number_entered * -1;
            
        }
        for (number_entered = number_entered; number_entered > 0; number_entered/=10){
            int lastdgt = number_entered%10;
            sum += lastdgt;
            reserve = lastdgt + " " + reserve + " ";       
            
        }
            
        System.out.println(reserve);
        System.out.println("The sum is = " + sum );
     
    }
    
}
```